# Проблема с получением события от Observable, shared

Tags: swift

Я создаю Observable и делаю share () для всех подписчиков, но onNext () приходит только для первого подписчика

```
let numbers = Observable<Int>.create { [unowned self] observer in
            print("eweeweeewe")
            let start = self.getStartNumber()
            observer.onNext(getStartNumber())
            return Disposables.create() }
            .share()
        
        
        numbers.debug("a")
            .subscribe()
        
        numbers.debug("b")
            .subscribe()
        
    }
    
    func getStartNumber() -> Int {
        return Int.random(in: 1...100000)
    }
```

```
Results:
2021-01-02 20:11:21.801: a -> subscribed
eweeweeewe
2021-01-02 20:11:21.802: a -> Event next(28847)
2021-01-02 20:11:21.803: b -> subscribed
```

Comment: Please translate your question into Russian.

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать **только на русском языке**. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.